# django object has no attribute 'count'

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-formwizard

I am learning django / python and I am stuck on an issue.

I have a view: `create_document.py` in which I want to count the number of name details from a models class: `NameDetails`.

I cannot get the correct syntax!

Here is my `models.py` code:

```
class NameDetails(FillableModelWithLanguageVersion):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name_details_prefix_title = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=25)
    name_details_first_name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=50)
    name_details_middle_name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    ....
```

Here is my `create_document.py` code in which I have a django wizard. I want to make sure the user has more than 1 name before they can create a document:

```
from app_name.core.models import NameDetails

class CreateDocumentWizard(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = 'documents/document_create.html'

    form_list = [
        core_forms.CreateDocumentWizardForm01,
        core_forms.CreateDocumentWizardForm02,
        core_forms.CreateDocumentWizardForm03,
        core_forms.CreateDocumentWizardForm04,
    ]

    def get_form_kwargs(self, step=None):
        kwargs = super(CreateDocumentWizard, self).get_form_kwargs(step)
        kwargs.setdefault('user', self.request.user)
        return kwargs

    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):

        name_details_count = NameDetails(user=self.request.user).count()
        if name_details_count < 1:
            return redirect(settings.MENU_DETAIL_LINK_NAME_DETAILS)
```

When I use the line to determine the count of NameDetails of the user: `name_details_count = NameDetails(user=self.request.user).count()`, I get the following error:

**NameDetails' object has no attribute 'count'**

I have tried many permutations, but I am stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be like that in your get_context_data function:

```
name_details_count = NameDetails.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).count()
```

Comment: vaan3713, thanks, I think your code works (no error returned), but the redirect does not appear to work - code proceeds to wizard!

Comment: Did you try to debug the result of the **count**? check also that **settings.MENU_DETAIL_LINK_NAME_DETAILS** contains the right url

Comment: You can't return a redirect in `get_context_data()`, since the `SessionWizardView` won't return that value as a response.

Comment: van3713, thanks, the underlying issue is working - just have to work out the redirect issue.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment you're creating a brand new `NameDetails` instance with `request.user` as the user. Instead, you should query the database for existing `NameDetails` for the current user, and count them. You can query the database through `NameDetails.objects`:

```
name_details_count = NameDetails.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).count()
```

Comment: knbk, thanks - using your code: `name_details_count = NameDetails.objects.filter(user=request.user).count()` gives me the error: **global name 'request' is not defined**. Any suggestions?

Comment: It need **self** since **request** isn't a parameter passed to your function

Answer (score 2):

Each time you need to make a Django QuerySet youhave to go through the object manager **objects** so : `NameDetails.objects.` in order to make a count you need a list so you use `filter`:

```
name_details_count = NameDetails.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).count()
```

in case you need one element you use `get`:

```
name_details_count = NameDetails.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
```

for redirection use better [HttpResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) and make sure the link in setting is correct:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.MENU_DETAIL_LINK_NAME_DETAILS)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a Python or maybe even more generally, a programming question.

Your line:

```
name_details_count = NameDetails(user=self.request.user).count()
```

Is Calling the ***constructor*** of the `NameDetails` class and attempting to call a function `count` that doesn't exist on it (hence the error type).

To get a ***list*** of all `NameDetails` instances with that user, you use:

```
name_details = NameDetails.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

And to get the number of items in this list, you can simply use the python built-in `len()` function like so:

```
name_details_count = len(NameDetails.objects.filter(user=self.request.user))
```

Answer (score 0):

if wants all recodes count(without any filter) in a collection the use this:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
cl = pymongo.MongoClient(host="localhost", port=27017)
db = cl["database_name"]
print(db.get_collection("collection_name").estimated_document_count())
```